# IBInspectable properties stopped showing

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, interface-builder

I flagged three properties as IBInspectable and they were working great. Later I decided another three properties I had been using would also benefit from IBInspectable, so I tagged them as well.

After tagging the new set of three the previous set of three disappeared from Interface Builder. Of the new three, only one of them is showing up.

I've tried deleting and re-creating the properties, unflagging the new ones in hopes that the old ones will re-appear, deleting and re-creating my custom view in Interface Builder, force refreshing all views, shutting down and re-opening Xcode, and so far nothing has worked to bring them back.

Are there any other tricks I might be able to try to get this working once again?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Figured it out. Seems somewhere along the way I removed the explicit type declarations from the variable definitions.

Comment: I guess type inference isn't enough here. Thanks for sharing the solution!

Comment: To illustrate, even this line failed with type inference: `    @IBInspectable public var lightBackgroundColor = UIColor(red: 222.0/255, green:196.0/255, blue:160.0/255, alpha:1)
`

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me after adding @objc to some variables.

Comment: The same case happened with me, what did you do to fix it?